# Is it possible to do a Boolean OR search on Trello?

Tags: trello, search

Is it possible to do a boolean `OR` search (filter) in Trello? Like:

```
(list:doing OR label:green)
```

I tried the above (and variations like `+` instead of `OR` and removing the `()`. I also googled on it with no luck. But just wanted to make sure I hadn't missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Be careful though.

Yes. When you select multiple Labels while filtering cards, these are found using "OR"

(Open a board then Menu | Filter Cards to perform these search actions)

Example: Selecting Green and Yellow (you can name labels too) will find All cards that have Either Yellow OR Green attached.

Yes. When you enter words in the search text box.  These are found using OR

Example: Search "Mobile Desktop"  will find cards that have Either word Mobile OR Desktop.

Mixed, If you select any multiple options (labels, text in the Search box, select users or "Due in" options) these are combined using mixed AND and OR

Example: Select Green, Yellow and search: Mobile Desktop
Will return all cards that have Mobile OR Desktop AND marked Green OR Yellow

No. If you want to search "Doing" (or any) list only.  I know of no filter to search a single list.

Once you get the hang of it, you can do some powerful searches.

Good Luck

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that you meant BOARD level filtering.
Very cool, I'd never used Board filtering

Comment: Oh how I wish they would add a pure AND operator.  Searches have proven fairly useless to me without it.  For example it appears there's no way to do this most simple search:  Find cards that have label "At Home" AND label "Medium Energy Required."  For now I have to filter on one or the other and then just look through them all, mentally slendering the list to include only cards with the second label.  I'm planning to see if I can use the API to make a program to do this, but it's hard to find the time.

Comment: Seems that this is now finally there: if you activate your filter dialog (f shortcut), you can switch to AND instead of OR at the bottom with the two new options: "Matches any label and any member" and "Matches all labels and all members". I saw this first in Trello 2.10.5 on the mac desktop app.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this response set, and my reading of the manual, the answer is strictly NO. it is not possible to do the boolean | or function, distinct from the boolean & and function: you can do implicit OR by a list of labels, and you can do implicit AND by using search: with at least one

Answer (score 0):

#### This is not an answer

I intended on adding a comment but I do not have necessary 50 rep points yet in order to do so.  However, I *really* wanted to address **bubbleking's** issue in his comment dated **Apr 8**, therefore, apologies for the false answer.

bubbleking, have you tried typing this into the search bar?

`label:"at home" label:"medium energy required"`

This style works for me when I'm trying to search for cards that have *both* labels, which is what I think you are trying to do.